# Segmentation Fault, Inserting a Node in a Singly Linked List

Tags: c++, insert, segmentation-fault, nodes, singly-linked-list

I have written some code for inserting a node in a singly linked list at the "nth" position but when i run the project I receive a segmentation fault:11

When n == to sizeM I call the push_back which will enter insert the node at the end. When n == to 0 I call the push_font which will enter insert the node at the start. Both those functions work as I have made calls to them to check earlier in my main file. Before I make any calls to insert my list contains

440 330 110

with headM pointing to 440 which is the 0th position in the list.

then I make 3 calls to insert

insert(40,3)

insert(10,0)

insert(33,2)

and the list now should be 10 440 33 330 110 40

Im not sure what is wrong, but Im pretty sure it is something to do when I insert the 33.

this is my simpleList.h containing the class

```
#ifndef Lab9_Simple_List__SimpleList__
#define Lab9_Simple_List__SimpleList__

typedef int ListItem;

class SimpleList {
private:

class Node {
public:
    ListItem item;
    Node *next;
};

Node *headM;
int sizeM;

void destroy();
// Deallocate all nodes, and sets headM to zero.

void copy(const SimpleList& source);
// List becomes copy of source.

public:

SimpleList(): headM(0), sizeM(0) { /* Point one */}
// PROMISES: creates empty list.

SimpleList(const SimpleList& source) { copy(source); }// copy constructor

SimpleList& operator =(const SimpleList& rhs);  // assignment operator

~SimpleList() { destroy(); }   // destructor

int size() const {return sizeM;}

void push_back(const ListItem& item);
// PROMISES:
//    Adds a node with an item to the end of the list, and increments sizeM

void push_front(const ListItem& item);
// PROMISES:
//    Adds a node with an item to the beginning of the list, and increments
//    sizeM
void pop_back(const ListItem& item);
// PROMISES:
//    The last node int list is removed

const ListItem& at(int n)const;
// PROMISES:
//    An item is return at the nth position in the list.
//    if n is less than 0 or greater than or equal sizeM gives the error
//    message: "Illegal Access" and terminates the program

ListItem& at(int n);
// PROMISES:
//    An item is return at the nth position in the list.
//    if n is less than 0 or greater than or equal sizeM gives the error
//    message: "Illegal Access" and terminates the program

void insert(const ListItem& theItem, int n);
// PROMISES:
//    A node with a copy of theItem is inserted at the nth position, and sizeM
//    will be incremented if the operation of insert was successfull.
//    if n == sizeM calles push_back
//    if n == 0 calls push_front
//    if n < 0 or n > sizeM returns and does nothing.

void remove(int n);
//  PROMISES:
//    Does nothing if n < 0 or n > sizeM-1. Otherwise, if list is not empty
//    removes the node at the position n.
};

#endif /* defined(Lab9_Simple_List__SimpleList__) */
```

this is my file containing the member definitions the one that isn't working is the insert function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SimpleList.h"


SimpleList& SimpleList::operator =(const SimpleList& rhs)
{
if (this != &rhs) {
    destroy();
    copy(rhs);
}

sizeM = rhs.sizeM;
return *this;
}

ListItem& SimpleList::at(int n)
{
if(n < 0 || n >= sizeM)
{
    cout << "\n Illegal Access. Program Terminates...";
    exit(1);
}

Node * p = headM;
for(int i= 0; i < n; i++)
    p = p -> next;

// point four

return p -> item;
}

const ListItem& SimpleList::at(int n)const
{
if(n < 0 || n >= sizeM){
    cout << "\n Illegal Access. Program Terminates...";
    exit(1);
}

Node * p = headM;
for(int i= 0; i < n; i++)
    p = p -> next;

// point three - when reached for the first time
return p -> item;
}

void SimpleList::push_back(const ListItem& item)
{
Node *new_node = new Node;
if(new_node == NULL)
{
    cout << "\nNo memory available to create a node" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

new_node->item = item;

if (headM == 0) {
    new_node->next = headM;
    headM = new_node;
}
else
{
    Node* p = headM;
    while (p ->next  != NULL)
        p = p ->next;

    p -> next = new_node;
    new_node -> next = NULL;
}
sizeM++;

// point five - when reached for the third time
}


void SimpleList::push_front(const ListItem& item)
{
Node *new_node = new Node;
new_node->item = item;
new_node->next = headM;
headM = new_node;
sizeM++;

// point two
}

void SimpleList::destroy()
{

// This function is not properly designed.
cout << "\nSimpleList::destroy was called but didn't do the right job.";
headM = 0;
}


void SimpleList::copy(const SimpleList& source)
{

// this function is incomplete and is not properly designed. It doesnt do
// its job, makeing 'this' SimpleList object a copy of the scoure.

// The only effect of the next line is to tell the compiler
// not to generate an "unused argument" warning.  If you are going to complete
// this funciton, don't leave it in your solution.
(void) source;

cout << "\nSimpleList::copy was called but didn't do the right job."
<< "--program is terminated.\n";
exit(1);
}

void SimpleList::insert(const ListItem& theItem, int n)
{
if (n < 0 || n > sizeM)
    return;
else if (n == sizeM)
    push_back(theItem);
else if (n == 0)
    push_front(theItem);
else
{
    Node* new_node = new Node;
    new_node->item = theItem;
    Node* temp = headM;
    for(int i = 0; i < (n - 1) ; i++)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    } 
    new_node->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = new_node;
    sizeM++;
}
}

void SimpleList::remove(int n)
{
if( n < 0 || n > sizeM ) { 
    return;
}

Node* p = headM;

if(n == 0 && headM != NULL)
{
    Node* const p_doomed = headM;
    headM = p_doomed->next;
    delete p_doomed;
    --sizeM;
}
else{
    for(int c = 0; c < n - 1; c++ )
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    Node* const p_doomed = p->next;
    p->next = p_doomed->next;
    delete p_doomed;
    --sizeM;
}
}
```

and below is my main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#include "SimpleList.h"
#define EXERCISE_B

void print(const SimpleList& list);
// PROMISES: prints values in the list from first node (node number 0) to
//           the last node. 

int main()
{    
SimpleList list;

cout << "\nList just after creation -- is empty.";

list.push_front(50);
cout << "\nAfter calling push_front. list must have: 50\n";
print(list);

list.push_back(440);

list.at(0) = 770;
cout << "\nAfter calling push_back and at functions, list must have: 770  440\n";
print(list);

list.push_back(330);
list.push_back(220);
list.push_back(110);

cout << "\nAfter three more calls to push_back, list must have:"
"770, 440, 330, 220, 110\n";
print(list);

#if defined (EXERCISE_B)
list.remove(0);
list.remove(2);
cout << "\nAfter removing two nodes. list must have: 440, 330, 110\n";
print(list);
list.insert(40, 3); //insert node with the value of 40 at the 4th position
list.insert(20, -1); // do nothing
list.insert(30, 30000); // do nothing
list.insert(10, 0); //insert node with the value of 10 at the 1st position
list.insert(33, 2); // insert node with the value 33 at the 3rd position

cout << "\nTwo  more nodes inserted, must have: 10, 440, 33, 330, 110, 40\n";
print(list);

list.remove(0);
list.remove(1);
list.remove(2);
list.remove(3);
list.remove(4);
list.remove(5);
cout << "\nAfter 6 removes, list must have: 440, 330, 40: \n";
print(list);

#endif
return 0;

}


void print(const SimpleList& list)
{
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    cout << list.at(i) << "  ";
}
```

and this is the output I am receiving

```
Haydns-MacBook-Pro:desktop Haydn$ g++ lab9_EXE_A.cpp simpleList.cpp
Haydns-MacBook-Pro:desktop Haydn$ ./a.out 

List just after creation -- is empty.
After calling push_front. list must have: 50
50  
After calling push_back and at functions, list must have: 770  440
770  440  
After three more calls to push_back, list must have:770, 440, 330, 220, 110    
770  440  330  220  110  
After removing two nodes. list must have: 440, 330, 110
440  330  110  
Two  more nodes inserted, must have: 10, 440, 33, 330, 110, 40
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Work on your indentation and general formatting (also for plain-text). Also, are you sure that's a *minimal* example? See: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Seconding the indentation.  Though, as far as MCVE, if he could find and provide an MCVE, he most likely wouldn't have a question :).

Comment: @Deduplicator I asked this question earlier and everyone said provide a full example and so I have

Comment: @tomsmith Ah the capriciousness of StackOverflow. Can you add  link to your old question?

Comment: @tomsmith Giving a _full sample_ doesn't mean you should just thrown all of your code in here but giving a _minimal_ sample, that is fully compilable and reproduces the problem. Also a debugger would help to narrow what the problem is. (BTW there are tons of questions to be found here struggling with double linked lists)

Comment: @JonathanMee: Nothing capricious. They meant that he previously failed the "complete" part of Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. Which does not mean he should utterly fail the "minimal" part, nor that he shouldn't use proper indentation and formatting.

Comment: @Deduplicator Referring more to [tom smiths](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1809768/tom-smith)' perspective when I say "capriciousness". I was actually just hoping that between the two questions I could get a more scoped view of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the first line of `void SimpleList::remove(int n)`

```
if (n < 0 || n >= sizeM) {  // CHange to >= and not > !!!
```

**Explanation:**

If the function is called with `n` being `0` and if the list is already empty (meaning that `sizeM==0` and `headM==nullptr`), with your original core, `n<0 || n>sizeM` would be false.

This means that the function would go on, the e execution flow being:

```
...
p=headM;   // meaning that p is now nullptr
if (n == 0 && headM != NULL)  // false because `n==0 && headM==nullptr`
// if block ignored 
else{  // here: (n!=0 || headM==NULL)  
    for (int c = 0; c < n - 1; c++) // the condition is false 
    // the loop body is ignored
    Node* const p_doomed = p->next;  // ouch !!!! p is nullptr => segfault !!!
```

If the function is called with `n` being being exacly the size of your stack, which happens in your `main()` when you `remove(3)`, the situation is similar.  You try to access one time too much to the `p->next` when `p` is already `nullptr`.

Comment: -changing that to >= worked !!I thought it was something wrong with my insert but it was with my remove instead thank you